# Global modifier key press detection in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, macos-carbon

I'm trying to use Carbon's function `RegisterEventHotKey` to create a hotkey for when the command key is pressed. I'm using it like so:

```
InstallEventHandler(GetApplicationEventTarget(), handler, 1, &eventType, nil, nil)
RegisterEventHotKey(UInt32(cmdKey), 0, hotKeyID, GetApplicationEventTarget(), 0, &hotKeyRef)
```

However, it doesn't call `handler` when I only use the command key. The handler is called if I replace `cmdKey` with any other non-modifier key code.

Does anyone have any suggestions that would allow the app to globally recognize when the command key is pressed? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add Global Monitor For Events matching `.flagsChanged` to your view controller so you can check its modifierFlags intersection with deviceIndependentFlagsMask and check the resulting keys.

> Declaration

```
class func addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching mask: NSEventMask, handler block: @escaping (NSEvent) -> Void) -> Any?
```

> installs an event monitor that receives copies of events posted to
>   other applications. Events are delivered asynchronously to your app
>   and you can only observe the event; you cannot modify or otherwise
>   prevent the event from being delivered to its original target
>   application. Key-related events may only be monitored if accessibility
>   is enabled or if your application is trusted for accessibility access
>   ([see AXIsProcessTrusted()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58405058/2303865)). Note that your handler will not be called
>   for events that are sent to your own application.

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .flagsChanged) {
            switch $0.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) {
            case [.shift]:
                print("shift key is pressed")
            case [.control]:
                print("control key is pressed")
            case [.option] :
                print("option key is pressed")
            case [.command]:
                print("Command key is pressed")
            case [.control, .shift]:
                print("control-shift keys are pressed")
            case [.option, .shift]:
                print("option-shift keys are pressed")
            case [.command, .shift]:
                print("command-shift keys are pressed")
            case [.control, .option]:
                print("control-option keys are pressed")
            case [.control, .command]:
                print("control-command keys are pressed")
            case [.option, .command]:
                print("option-command keys are pressed")
            case [.shift, .control, .option]:
                print("shift-control-option keys are pressed")
            case [.shift, .control, .command]:
                print("shift-control-command keys are pressed")
            case [.control, .option, .command]:
                print("control-option-command keys are pressed")
            case [.shift, .command, .option]:
                print("shift-command-option keys are pressed")
            case [.shift, .control, .option, .command]:
                print("shift-control-option-command keys are pressed")
            default:
                print("no modifier keys are pressed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing. My previous implementation was a little different now that I checked. Yours works like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: I dont understand why, but when my CapsLock is Activated the "cases" stop to work. And every print is "no modifier keys are pressed"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59592581/2303865

Comment: Did you try to match their cases? like `case [.capsLock, .control, .option, .command]`?