# How to detect Caps Lock status on macOS with Swift without a window?

Tags: swift, macos, detect, modifier, nsevent

I have tried `KeyDown` and `NSEvent`, but they require a `NSWindow` object to be active. My hope is that I can put an app on the status bar and alert the user when it has pressed *CapsLock*, even if the user is in any other app. My app idea doesn't have a window for settings or anything else, is just an indicator. Can it even be done? I am guessing the `AppDelegate` but can't figure out how to make it receive modifier events. Any help really appreciated!

I have looked on stack overflow for a "duplicate" but no one has ever asked this question as far as I searched.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global modifier key press detection in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927843/global-modifier-key-press-detection-in-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to monitor the NSEvent modifier flags changed for [capslock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/modifierflags/1642462-capslock). The easiest way is to create a method that takes a NSEvent and check if the  `modifierFlags` property intersection with `.deviceIndependentFlagsMask` contains `.capsLock`:

```
func isCapslockEnabled(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
    event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask).contains(.capsLock)
}
```

---

Now you just need to add global monitoring event to your applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .flagsChanged, handler: flagsChanged)
}
```

---

And create a method to deal with the event of `flagsChanged`:

```
func flagsChanged(with event: NSEvent) {
    print("Capslock is Enabled:", isCapslockEnabled(with: event))
}
```

---

Edit/update:

As already mentioned in comments, to check the initial state of the capsLock key you can check the `NSEvent` `ModifierFlags` `capsLock` property [capsLock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/modifierflags/1642462-capslock)

```
NSEvent.ModifierFlags.capsLock
```

Comment: how would you check to see if caps lock is down upon launch?
I.E. what if the event occurred BEFORE launch

like KeyMap long ago

Comment: For initial state you can use `NSEvent.modifierFlags` static property.